# Nested ng-repeat issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have created a topics and a subtopics table, but I want each subtopic to reference only one topic without changing. Right now, my code updates the scope to the most recent ng-repeat call on all of my divs. The issue is if 2 or more rows are open, then all of the rows update their scope to match the last opened row. I have set-up an example on plunkr:

- https://plnkr.co/edit/hJV5bNkBiAlz0qr2i1kg?p=preview

My view looks like this:

```
 <table class="section-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr><td class="section-topic">Testing</td></tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="subtopic in main.subtopics">
              <td data-ng-click="subtopic.isCollapsed = !subtopic.isCollapsed" class="section-subtopic">{{subtopic.label}}
                <div uib-collapse="subtopic.isCollapsed" expanded="main.showContent(subtopic.id)">
              <div data-ng-repeat="content in main.contents"  class="topic-content">
              <div data-ng-bind="content.content"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

I think there is an issue with the inner ng-repeat, but I am not certain. Is there a way for the subtopics to match their topic without updating their scope when 2 or more table rows are open?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your showContent method. Beside the obvious error of declaring var testArr in each condition, this method set the array every time the showContent is called.

You need to save the sub array inside your topics object, so you can display each one accordingly